Authorization issue to login with Microsoft Entra ID credentials like service principal in the Backstage
I'm facing the error message below when I tried configure the Backstage in my project in Azure Devops. I gave all permisson in the azure service principal but not working yet. I've analyzed the message error but I couldn't solve atough run many options.
{"error":{"name":"InputError","message":"Error: Unable to read url, Error:
https://dev.azure.com/epharmapbm/OxygenCatalog/_git/OxygenCatalogNegocios?path=%2Fcatalog-info.yaml
could not be read as
https://dev.azure.com/epharmapbm/OxygenCatalog/_apis/git/repositories/OxygenCatalogNegocios/items?api-version=6.0&path=%2Fcatalog-info.yaml
, 401 Unauthorized","stack":"InputError: Error: Unable to read url, Error:
https://dev.azure.com/epharmapbm/OxygenCatalog/_git/OxygenCatalogNegocios?path=%2Fcatalog-info.yaml
could not be read as
https://dev.azure.com/epharmapbm/OxygenCatalog/_apis/git/repositories/OxygenCatalogNegocios/items?api-version=6.0&path=%2Fcatalog-info.yaml
, 401 Unauthorized\n at DefaultLocationService.processEntities (/Users/swirf/Documents/github-epharma/Oxygen/node_modules/@backstage/plugin-catalog-backend/src/service/DefaultLocationService.ts:110:15)\n at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n at DefaultLocationService.dryRunCreateLocation (/Users/swirf/Documents/github-epharma/Oxygen/node_modules/@backstage/plugin-catalog-backend/src/service/DefaultLocationService.ts:148:32)\n at  (/Users/swirf/Documents/github-epharma/Oxygen/node_modules/@backstage/plugin-catalog-backend/src/service/createRouter.ts:253:24)"},"request":{"method":"POST","url":"/locations?dryRun=true"},"response":{"statusCode":400}}
If anyone can help I appreciate very much.n
I've been configuring the Backstage for a long time and the azure service principal has all permissions that are necessary according the Backstage documentation in GitHub.

Basically, I need access repositories in Azure Devops using azure service principal.
